# Question about .stop() in jQuery !

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I know that .stop() function is used to stop animation .. but where should I put it when I have this code:

```
$('#home').mouseover(function(){
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({
        "width":"5px",
        "opacity":"1.0"
    },1);
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({
        "height":"15px"
    },1000);
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({
        "width":"60px"
    },1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({
        "opacity" :"0.0"
    },1000);
});
```

And I want to stop the animation when I leave the icon with the mouse pointer !
I've wathced many jQuery videos but the examples are with one animation .. I've got 3 !?

Thanks you ! : )

Answer (score 2):

This should do it....

```
$('#home').mouseover(function(){ 
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({ "width":"5px", "opacity":"1.0" },1); 
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({ "height":"15px" },1000); 
    $('.subhome_icon').animate({ "width":"60px" },1000); })
.mouseout(function(){ 
    $('.subhome_icon').stop().animate({ "opacity" :"0.0" },1000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
.mouseout(function(){ 
    $('.subhome_icon').stop(true).animate({ 
                            "opacity" :"0.0" },
                         1000); 
});
```

(*notice the `true` argument passed to the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method*)

This clears the queued animations so it truly stops at the current state.

Comment: Thank you guys !! YOU ARE AWESOME !! : ) (bow) Everithing works perfectly : )